# How can I Switch-In or Switch-Out Partition where table has non storage aligned indexes on it?

Tags: sql-server

My Database tables looks similar to this one:
[image: Sample DB Diagram]

I've partitioned table on TimeStamp in Logtable. This LogTabel is refenced by CHILD_TABLE WITH LogId.

Now, I want to perform Switch partition but getting below warning and not allowing me to perform an action:

[image: Manage Partition Wizard]

I tried to remove Non-Clustered Index on LogID but cannot do it without dropping all Foreign-Key relationships.

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 2):

You have to drop the foreign keys and index.
From BOL:

> No foreign key from another table can reference the source table. The
> source table cannot be referenced by a foreign key in another table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191160(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN